Angular 18.0.5 not seeing the interceptor
Angular is not aknowledging the interceptor.
So basically I executed
ng generate interceptor JwtInterceptor

and setup set it up to add the token to the header :
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export const jwtInterceptorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  console.log('Interceptor invoked'); 
  let token: string | null = localStorage.getItem("access_token");

  console.log("Token from localStorage:", token);
  if (token) { 
    const clonedRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set(
        'x-auth-token',token
      )
    });
  
    return next(clonedRequest).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            console.error('Unauthorized request:', err);
          } else {
            console.error('HTTP error:', err);
          }
        } else {
          console.error('An error occurred:', err);
        }
  
        return throwError(() => err); 
      })
    );
  } else {
    console.log("no token")
    return next(req);
  }


};

Then added the interceptor in the provider :
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient(
    withInterceptors([jwtInterceptorInterceptor]),
  ),]
};

also tried the Di pattern in app.config.ts :
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useValue: jwtInterceptorInterceptor,
    multi: true

  },]
};


And i even put the provider inside the component as well which shouldn't be done as it might double trigger it or cause a conflict i'm assuming :
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrl: './profile.component.css',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useValue: jwtInterceptorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
})

I tried getting rid of all the interceptor's code and leaving only the loggings but still the interceptor is not being hit at all in any scenario :

Note

This is the reference that seemed to me the most accurate to follow :
text
I'm a week years old on angluar.
I went throught all stackoverflow issues


could you share a stackblitz with the minimal reproducible code for debugging, I think you are not bootstraping the application properly like mixing standalone and modular

you're not wrong if i understood you correctly, either way I solved it (read last answer).

the app.config.ts was the wrong wrapper in which the intercepted should be callled, instead i called it in bootstrapApplication() in main.ts and it worked :


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideProtractorTestingSupport(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([jwtInterceptorInterceptor])),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));



